# Retrieve a file from a URL and serve it with the same headers

Tags: php

Currently I'm working on building a SMF mod that enables SSL and one thing that keeps poping up is the issue of user embedded content (like images) and other sorts of things not being served from sites with SSL. I'm after a way to build a sort of proxy script that will run on my site and when passed a URL, will retrieve the file, maintain most of the headers (eg. mime type) and then serve the file again. This way it looks like the image or whatever is actually being served from a SSL enabled site when infact its not.

Comment: I would look into cURL and using it to retrieve the image and its headers. Then manually set the headers you want and display the image.

Comment: Thought of this. Is there a way to request just headers from a server? That way I could minimize the amount of bandwidth used by the server by only redownloading the image when its been modified, otherwise pass on the "Not modified" status code back down to the client. Or maybe I could pass up the "Last Modified" header from the client to the server and then see if the server responds with not modified?

Comment: Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);`. Not sure though, never done it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try! Just out of sheer curiosity, do you possibly know where I could find a decent summary of how to use cURL in PHP? Don't go out of your way to find one, was just wondering if you had one bookmarked or something :)

Comment: Is this not sufficient? http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Alright so I'm on the right track. However, I want to use cURL to download a file to a variable, but also get headers at the same time so I can send some to the user however I don't want the headers in the same variable as the file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments! Just for those who want to do this in the future, heres the script I'm using:

```
<?php
    $requestURL = filter_var($_REQUEST["url"], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    if(filter_var($requestURL, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED))
    {
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']))
        {
            // Load the headers from the destination server.
            $uri_info = new URIInfo($requestURL);
            if($uri_info->info['filetime'] == strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']))
            {
                header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
            }
            else
            {
                //Serve a new copy of the file, its changed :O
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $requestURL);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
                $data = curl_exec($ch);
                $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
                curl_close($ch);

                //Display the image in the browser
                header('Content-type: ' . $info['content_type']);
                header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $info['filetime']));
                header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); //Stop CloudFlare!
                echo $data;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Just serve the file, they obviously don't have a copy of it!
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $requestURL);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            //Display the image in the browser
            header('Content-type: ' . $info['content_type']);
            header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $info['filetime']));
            header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); //Stop CloudFlare!
            echo $data;
        }
    }    
    exit();
?>




<?php

    class URIInfo 
    {
        public $info;
        public $header;
        private $url;

        public function __construct($url)
        {
            $this->url = $url;
            $this->setData();
        }

        public function setData() 
        {
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $this->header = curl_exec($curl);
            $this->info = curl_getinfo($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
        }

        public function getFiletime() 
        {
            return $this->info['filetime'];
        }
    }

?>
```